# Number of tuples that have odd sum

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

> Question: Given $r$ natural numbers $b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_r $ and consider the sum
> $$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_r,$$
> where $x_i's \in \{0,1,\cdots,b_i\}$. Is there an explicit formula for the number of tuples $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_r)$ such that the sum is odd?

My attempt is by using the generating function, but I don't see a way to get an explicit form.
The generating function is
$$(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{b_1})(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{b_2})\cdots(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{b_r})$$
which can be simplified to
$$\frac{(x^{b_1}-1)(x^{b_2}-1)\cdots(x^{b_r}-1)}{(x-1)^r}.$$
Then the sum of the coefficients of odd $n$-th term in the expansion is the number I'm looking for. But it is not simple to expand it. So I'm asking help to this question. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the use of "natural numbers" is not standard. Some people include $0$ while others don't. Can the $b_i$'s be $0$?

Comment: If $n$ is the total number of tuples, then the number of tuples with odd sum is $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$

Comment: @jjagmath not including $0$.

Comment: @DanielMathias Wow, I didn't expect the answer to be such clean. Do you mind explaining your steps?

Comment: Intuitively, the parity of the sum is dependent on the parity of an arbitrarily chosen $x_i$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. Let $f_n$ be the number of tuples $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_r)$ such that the sum is $n$. As you have already determined, these are the coefficients of the generating function
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n x^n=\prod_{i=1}^r(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{b_i})
\end{equation}
So the number of such tuples where the sum is odd is given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{n\geq 0, \text{ odd}}f_n
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}\right)f_n\\
&=\frac{1}{2}[f(1)-f(-1)]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\prod_{i=1}^r(1+b_i)-\prod_{i=1}^r\left(\frac{1-(-1)^{b_i}}{2}\right)\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Notice that that second product simplifies depending on whether or not any of the $b_i$ are even. Can you finish from here?